# How do I access both the drag and drop element in HTML?

Tags: html, dom, drag, drop

The 'dragenter' event fires when a dragged element enters a drop element. This event is attached to the drop element, so I can access that. Where is the dragged element?

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drop_event) one click away from the URL you referenced:

You have to keep track of it, using the dragstart event, yourself.

> ```
> let dragged = null;
>
> const source = document.getElementById("draggable");
> source.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
>   // store a ref. on the dragged elem
>   dragged = event.target;
> });
>
> const target = document.getElementById("droptarget");
> target.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
>   // prevent default to allow drop
>   event.preventDefault();
> });
>
> target.addEventListener("drop", (event) => {
>   // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
>   event.preventDefault();
>   // move dragged element to the selected drop target
>   if (event.target.className === "dropzone") {
>     dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
>     event.target.appendChild(dragged);
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: I'm still not clear how to associate each 'dragenter' or 'drop' event with each dragged element. In your example above, if I had 2 dragged elements, how would I know which one is triggering the  'dragenter' or 'drop' events?

Comment: @Anthony — How would you have 2 dragged elements?